# AJAX post not working

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm using jQuery and Codeigniter to update the database via AJAX. The following code does not seem to do anything or send anything to my controller when the button is clicked...

**jQuery:**

```
$("#button_submit1").click(function(e) {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: window.location.href,
        dataType: "json",
        data: $('#writereview_form').serialize() + '&ajax=true',
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
                    alert("yay");
                    //$("#writereview_box").fadeOut(1000);
        }
    });

    return false;

});
```

**HTML:**

```
<form action="http://mysite.com/places/writereview/2107" id="writereview_form" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">   

...
...

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Review" class="button_submit" id="button_submit1">
```

Any ideas why the ajax data is not being sent?

Comment: Have you checked that there are no JavaScript errors in the page?

Comment: Yup no javascript errors using Chrome's console. Nothing happens when I click the submit button

Comment: because your already submiting it with your input type submit button. trying adding a plan link with a button style and putting onclick="Functin"

Comment: Try to change type="submit" to type="button"

Comment: @RPM: The `return false` will prevent the default `submit`. My suspect would be `window.location.href`. Do you see the XHR request in chrome's dev tools?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case its better to bind to the 'submit' event on the form and then use `preventDefault()` to stop the HTML submission and use Ajax instead.

You should also use the form's action instead of `window.location`

```
$("#writereview_form").submit(function(e) {
  var $this = $(this);
  e.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: $this.attr('action'),
      dataType: "json",
      data: $this.serialize() + '&ajax=true',
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
                  alert("yay");
                  //$("#writereview_box").fadeOut(1000);
      }
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try withiut using `window.location.href` and giving url as  `url: "page.php",`