# JQuery AJAX Post throwing error in Firefox

Tags: asp.net, json, jquery, firefox

I am having an issue with firefox for jquery ajax post. This functionality is working IE (not in firefox). In IE controller is reaching to `[webmethod]` in server side. But this is not happening to firefox.

I don't understand the problem. I place javascript debug in firebug, nothing showing there too.

```
var save = function(saveUrl) {
    var $value = $("#Body_hiddenClientId");
    var $container = $("#grid");
    var handsontable = $container.data('handsontable');
    var tableData = JSON.stringify(handsontable.getData());
    var input = JSON.stringify({"input": tableData});

    $.ajax({
        url: saveUrl,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: input,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function(res) {

            if (res.d === 'ok') {

                // handsontable('render');
                $('#grid').handsontable('destroy');
                getData();
            }
            $.unblockUI();
        },
        error: function(xhr) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(xhr.responseText));
            //  alert(xhr);
        }
    });
};
```

[image]

[image]

### Update:

finally I captured watch window in firebug. After this error page is refreshing.. It is hard to hold error.
[image]

I tried cross domain by adding `Header` in server side, but still doesn't work.

```
Sub Application_BeginRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ' Fires at the beginning of each request
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
End Sub
```

Comment: Which version of FF? Which platform? Does [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WZPMx/) also trigger the error handler?

Comment: seems like error is not in your JavaScript code, but in your server code. Try this trick: `error: function (xhr) {global_xhr = xhr}`. Then open console and see what is in your `global_xhr` variable

Comment: some reason my page is reloading completely. I cannot catch errors.

Comment: ` error: function (xhr) {
global_xhr = xhr
console.log('data of ' + xhr.responseText);
alert(xhr.responseText);
} ` at global_xhr I have breakpoint. cursur is coming there and automatically refreshing the page. I have profile started still I am not able to see console statement in console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is resolved by this post.

```
  var $this = $(this);
  e.preventDefault();
```

before I called Ajax post.

[AJAX post not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6779218/ajax-post-not-working)